# Code runs slower with Multiprocessing.pool.map than without

Tags: python, multiprocessing

This code simulates loading a CSV, parsing it and loading it int a pandas dataframe. I would like to parallelize this problem so that it runs faster, but my pool.map implementation is actually slower than the serial implementation.

The csv is read as one big string and first split into lines and then split into values. It is an irregularly formatted csv with recurring headers so I cannot use the pandas read_csv. At least not that I know how.

My idea was to simply read in the file as string, split the long string into four parts (one for each core) and then process each chunk separately in parallel. This it turns out is slower than the serial version.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import datetime
import pandas as pd

def data_proc(raw):
    pre_df_list = list()  
    for item in (i for i in raw.split('\n') if i and not i.startswith(',')):
        if ' ' in item and ',' in item:
            key, freq, date_observation = item.split(' ')
            date, observation = date_observation.split(',')
            pre_df_list.append([key, freq, date, observation])
    return pre_df_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    raw = '\n'.join([f'KEY FREQ DATE,{i}' for i in range(15059071)]) # instead of loading csv
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    pre_df_list = data_proc(raw)
    df = pd.DataFrame(pre_df_list, columns=['KEY','FREQ','DATE','VAL'])
    end = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(end - start)

    pool = Pool(processes=4) 

    start = datetime.datetime.now()

    len(raw.split('\n'))
    number_of_tasks = 4
    chunk_size = int((len(raw) / number_of_tasks))

    beginning = 0
    multi_list = list()
    for i in range(1,number_of_tasks+1):
        multi_list.append(raw[beginning:chunk_size*i])
        beginning = chunk_size*i

    results =  pool.imap(data_proc, multi_list)
#    d = results[0]
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

#   I haven'f finished conversion to dataframe since previous part is not working yet
#    df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['SERIES_KEY','Frequency','OBS_DATE','val'])
    end = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(end - start)
```

EDIT: the serial version finishes in 34 seconds and the parallel after 53 seconds on my laptop. When I started working on this, my initial assumption was that I would be able to get it down to 10-ish seconds on a 4 core machine.

It looks like the parallel version I posted never finishes. I changed the pool.map call to pool.imap and now it works again. Note it has to be ran from the command line, not Spyder.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein Appreciate you taking a look! I updated the question now.

Comment: Also, I expect your generator was intended to be `'\n'.join([f.'KEY,FREQ,DATA,{i}' for i in range(15059071)]) .  Otherwise, your split will fail all the time.

Answer (score 0):

**In General:**

Multiprocessing isn't always the best way to do things.  It takes overhead to create and manage the new processes, and to synchronize their output.  In a relatively simple case, like parsing 150M lines of small text, you may or may not get a big time savings from using the multiprocessor.

There are a lot of other confounding variables - process load on the machine, number of processors, any access to I/O being spread across the processor (that one is not a problem in your specific case), the potential to fill up memory and then deal with page swaps... The list can keep growing.  There are times multiprocessing is the ideal, and there are times where it makes matters worse.  (In my production code, I have one place where I left a comment: "Using multiprocesing here took 3x longer than not.  Just using regular map...")

**Your specific case**

However, without knowing your exact system specifications, I think that you should have a performance improvment from properly done multiprocessing.  You may not; this task may be small enough that it's not worth the overhead.  However, there are several issues with your code that will result in your multiprocessing path taking longer.  I'll call out the ones that catch my attention

```
len(raw.split('\n'))
```

This line is very expensive, and accomplishes nothing.  It goes through every line of your raw data, splits it, takes the length of the result, then throws out the split data and the len.  You likely want to do something like:

```
splitted = raw.split('\n')
splitted_len = len(splitted) # but I'm not sure where you need this.
```

This would save the split data, so you could make use of it later, in your for loop.  As it is right now, your for loop operates on raw, *which has not been split*.  So instead of, e.g., running on `[first_part, second_part, third_part, fourth_part]`, you're running on `[all_of_it, all_of_it, all_of_it, all_of_it]`.  This, of course, is a **HUGE** part of your performance degradation - you're doing the same work x4!

I expect, if you take care of splitting on `\n` outside of your processing, that's all you'll need to get an improvement from multiprocessing.  (Note, you actually don't need any special processing for 'serial' vs. 'parallel' - you can test it decently by using `map` instead of `pool.map`.)

Here's my take at re-doing your code.  It moves the line splitting out of the data_proc function, so you can focus on whether splitting the array into 4 chunks gives you any improvement.  (Other than that, it makes each task into a well-defined function - that's just style, to help clarify what's testing where.)

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import datetime
import pandas as pd

def serial(raw):
    pre_df_list = data_proc(raw)
    return pre_df_list

def parallel(raw):
    pool = Pool(processes=4) 

    number_of_tasks = 4
    chunk_size = int((len(raw) / number_of_tasks))

    beginning = 0
    multi_list = list()
    for i in range(1,number_of_tasks+1):
        multi_list.append(raw[beginning:chunk_size*i])
        beginning = chunk_size*i

    results =  pool.map(data_proc, multi_list)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    pre_df_list = []
    for r in results:
        pre_df_list.append(r)
    return pre_df_list

def data_proc(raw):
    # assume raw is pre-split by the time you're here
    pre_df_list = list()  
    for item in (i for i in if i and not i.startswith(',')):
        if ' ' in item and ',' in item:
            key, freq, date_observation = item.split(' ')
            date, observation = date_observation.split(',')
            pre_df_list.append([key, freq, date, observation])
    return pre_df_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # don't bother with the join, since we would need it in either case
    raw = [f'KEY FREQ DATE,{i}' for i in range(15059071)] # instead of loading csv

    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    pre_df_list = serial(raw)
    end = datetime.datetime.now()
    print("serial time: {}".format(end - start))

    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    pre_df_list = parallel(raw)
    end = datetime.datetime.now()
    print("parallel time: {}".format(end - start))

    # make the dataframe.  This would happen in either case
    df = pd.DataFrame(pre_df_list, columns=['KEY','FREQ','DATE','VAL'])
```

Comment: Nearly. The overhead in multiprocessing is mostly copying data (pickling and unpickling) between workers and the main process. There are some objects that can be shared between processes without copying as they are stored in shared memory with access to them protected with locks. I wasn't sure that a dataframe was one of them. If it was I was going to suggest that the workers make a dataframe rather than return a list as then there would only be one copy to combine the parts of the dataframe.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, Scott. I ran it on my machine (after fixing a couple of minor bugs) but it finishes even slower than my code - 63 seconds.

Comment: @DanD. That kind of makes sense. I tried printing the start/end times at the start and end of the data_proc() function and each of the 4 processes takes about 10 seconds to finish. But than strangely it takes the rest of the time for the pool.imap to return. I will try now compressing the string before passing it on to data_proc, to see if this alleviates the communication overhead. I mean, I am only passing it 4 lists, there is no constant back ad forth communication, so I am assuming it is the size of every item being passed that is slowing it down.

Comment: One more comment, raw is being split inside the loop by doing raw[beginning:chunk_size*i]. So it isn't correct that the entire raw is being passed to the data_proc or that the work is being repeated.

Comment: @delica But raw wasn't split originally.  It was just one long string.  And strings can be treated as an array, but if so, you're doing it on a character, not a line basis.  This means you'll almost certainly end up splitting one line among your sets.  So yes, it was splitting, but not correctly.  Also, note that my code called map, not imap - that should be an important difference.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein I am not sure what you mean when you say 'originally'. Can you show me the original code where it wasn't being split?

Comment: Print multi_list after your for loop that makes it.  You'll see it's not broken on line boundaries.